# $(X,Y)$ is the function o the total density $f(x,y)\neq0$ in the first quadrant, and $f(x,y)=0$ in the second, third and fourth quadrants.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

$(X,Y)$ is the function of the total density $f(x,y)\neq0$ in the first quadrant, and $f(x,y)=0$ in the second, third and fourth quadrants.

Calculate: $P(Y>4-4X).$

**MY CALCULATIONS:**

The only useful part of pdf is that of the first quadrant - which is non-zero. Hence technically we can say that our reduced pdf is:

$f(x,y)\neq0$ ; $\forall$ $x>0, y>0$

Hence $P(Y>4-4X)=$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{4-4x}^{+\infty}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$

I am not sure whether this is the final answer because I think I am missing out on $f(x,y)$ but there is no information from which I can calculate it either. Kindly guide please.

Comment: Hint: draw the corresponding region ($y > 4 - 4x$).

Comment: Not correct. It should be $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \int_{4-4x}^{\infty}f(x,y) \,dy\,dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y) \,dy\,dx$

Comment: For $x \gt 1, 4-4x$ is negative but you cannot have $y \lt 0$.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you. I got my mistake. I have one question though about $f(x,y)$, which is do I have to calculate $f(x,y)$ OR is it enough leave it there?

Comment: If $f(x, y)$ is not given then there is no way to find out